# JButton array buttons not visible unless button not from array is added

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have a array of JButtons that do not want to be visible unless I add another JButton before the loop for the array of buttons. 
Window class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
private Container mContainer = new Container();

public Window()
{
    super();
    this.setTitle("Calculator");
    this.setSize(200, 300);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mContainer.setBorder(null);
    mContainer.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    mContainer.setOpaque(true);
    this.setContentPane(mContainer);

    //Panels
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    center.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    center.setBorder(null);
    JPanel displayOutput = new JPanel();
    displayOutput.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    this.getContentPane().add(panel);

    //TextArea
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1, 20);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    textArea.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 60));

    //Panel Layouts
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    center.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4, 2, 2));

    //Add other panel elements
    displayOutput.add(textArea);
    panel.add(displayOutput, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //For some reason adding this makes the array of buttons appear
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("1");
    center.add(btnNewButton);

    //Create buttons
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
       CalcButtons cButtons[] = new CalcButtons[20];
       cButtons[i] = new CalcButtons();
    //Add buttons to center box below output
        center.add(cButtons[i]);
    //Sets fourth column of buttons in cyan.
       if(((i + 1) % 4) == 0){
            cButtons[i].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }
    }

    //Add panel to window
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Container Class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Container extends JPanel {

    public Container() {
        super();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Button Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CalcButtons extends JButton
{
    public CalcButtons()
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBorder(null);
    }
}
```

This code then produced this:

[image: buttons displayed]

However if I remove this:

```
//For some reason adding this makes the array of buttons appear
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("1");
center.add(btnNewButton);
```

It produces this:

[image: buttons not displayed]

Comment: Just so you know - you are not really creating an array of buttons. You are creating 20 arrays, creating a button in one position in the array, and then discarding the array.

Comment: as RealSkeptic says, you should move this line out of the loop `CalcButtons cButtons[] = new CalcButtons[20];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the size of your buttons are 0. You have set the border to null and there is no icon or text set. So when GridLayout calls getPreferredSize() on your buttons they return a size of 0,0 (width, height). When you add the JButton with a 1 in it then all of sudden one component has size. Since Gridlayout makes all components the same size you now can see your buttons. If you want your buttons to be blank but also be drawn set your border to an empty border with a size of 1 or greater on each edge.

Comment: please to add pack() to your answer, with some explanations about, before code line JFrame.setVisible